# Get email_address's from item.cc_recipients exchangelib

Tags: python, exchangelib

I think I'm stuck looking for an efficient solution

```
 print(item.cc_recipients)
```

I got the result:

```
[Mailbox(name='xxx1@gmail.com', email_address='xxx1@gmail.com', routing_type='SMTP', mailbox_type='OneOff', item_id=None), Mailbox(name='xxxx xxxx', email_address='xxx.xxx@xx.xx.com', routing_type='SMTP', mailbox_type='Mailbox', item_id=None)]
```

but I would like to download a list with just email addresses ?, Is there a quick solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.cc_recipients` returns a list of [Mailbox](https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/exchangelib/properties.html#exchangelib.properties.Mailbox) items. A `Mailbox` item has an `email_address` attribute. To convert `cc_recipients` to a list of email addresses, do:

```py
print([m.email_address for m in item.cc_recipients])
```

Comment: Perfecto ! Thanks :)